# How to link ETW start/stop Opcode concurrent events

Tags: c#, etw

I'm using ETW, and logging some events that have stop & stop opcodes, e.g.

```
[Event(1, Task = Tasks.ActivateTask, Opcode = EventOpcode.Start)]
public void ActivateTaskStart(string TaskName)
{
    if (IsEnabled())
    {
        WriteEvent(1, TaskName);
    }
}

[Event(2, Task = Tasks.ActivateTask, Opcode = EventOpcode.Stop)]
public void ActivateTaskStop(string TaskName)
{
    if (IsEnabled())
    {
        WriteEvent(2, TaskName);
    }
}
```

If I have two threads that are both logging ActivateTask start/stop events, how do I make sure the events are correctly paired up? e.g. If I have:

- Thead-A: ActivateTaskStart
- Thead-B: ActivateTaskStart

then later

- Thead-A: ActivateTaskStop
- Thead-B: ActivateTaskStop

from my reading of the ETW docs, it will default to assuming that the Stop event belongs to the most recent, unpaired, Start event - but I want to make sure I'm linking the correct Start/Stop events.

Is that possible? If so, how?

To make this more complicated, there's a chance that the Start and Stop events might be coming from different threads (if I need to, I should be able to make the threads sticky).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [ActivityTrackig and works since .Net 4.6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2015/09/14/exploring-eventsource-activity-correlation-and-causation-features.aspx). To get this working automatically, you can't use own Thread implementations, you have to wrap all calls into System.Threading.Tasks.Task calls.